# Teamviewer - Send Control Key to Mac from Windows

Tags: xcode, xcode4, interface-builder, remote-access, xcode4.6

I'm TV'ing from a remote location to my mac to play around with XCode (on a windows pc). Within the interface builder, I'm trying to perform the control drag action. I tried pressing the ctrl button and dragging a view controller but nothing happens. If it's of any significant, I have send key combinations checked.

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, instead of control dragging try control clicking on the object you wanted to drag from. The black pop up box that lists the object's outlets etc will appear, and from there you can left-click drag from the circles to wherever you want.

Comment: It doesn't help for layout stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

Try the windows key, it will function similar to OSX Command key

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm on Mac using TeamViewer 10.0.52680, right-click or control-click on an object on a story board and simply left-click dragging to the view controller will create the proper referencing outlet.

If you have issues with the right click, go to TeamViewer preferences on the machine you are removing from, go to Advanced > General and select "Use control and mouse click as right mouse-click". This will enable you to send the control button and left click combination to your remote machine as a right click.